# using <a href=""> in ipad applications

Tags: jquery

i am developing a site which is using normal jquery.

in this page i have 3 links.when i click on that i have mentioned href attribute to perticular divs.it is working fine in desktop applications. But coming to iPad it is not working.
If we touch directly to that link with out touching or scrolling the page. If we touch or  scroll the web page before clicking or touching that link it is working fine.

pls help me...

`<a href>` is not working with out scrolling or with out touching the web page in iPad
first time when the page loads it is working fine. After that it wont work if we directly clicks on that(with out scrolling or with out touching the web page).

my code is:

```
      <li><a href="#hometab" class="scroll " id="welcome">TEXT1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#aboutustab" class="scroll " id="aboutus">TEXT2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contacttab" class="scroll " id="contactus">TEXT3</a></li>
```

some text..............



some text..............



some text..............

Comment: Welcome to the forum you should write the proper word its not the site for chatting ...

Comment: are you initializing your functions when the page loads? Also, not that it would make a difference but you might want to get rid of the extra space in the class name "scroll" not "scroll "